# MVC - Store variable to next request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, var, httpcontext, viewbag

I have one method which receive two parameters (int?, string). Action in my controller must save this variables and return view with form. After form is returned from client I need this variables from previous request. I can pass them to view with ViewBag and add to form as hidden, but it is very dangerous, anyone can change it in browser. Any ideas?
I think this question does not make sense.
If I have method which receives two parameters with HTTP GET method, so it's no difference where user change this two variables, in get method or in form.
If I store it in server side, he can change when passing parameters to first method and server will store wrong variables.
For example:
http://www.someurl.com/Controller/Action/?id=123&key=someKey
I can change parameters by editing url, so absurdly store it as variable at server side to make sure that user wouldn't change it by editig hidden fields. Moreover I can check if key is the same key as in database with this id.

Comment: Yes, a malicious user can use tools such as fiddler to change the value of your hidden inputs.

Comment: Why not use session then?

Comment: Session time is 20 or 30 minutes. User can open this form and submit it when the time of session is out. Users don't like exceptions.

Comment: What are you storing in the variable that it would be dangerous to change?

Comment: Key and id will be used to validate request and make some changes in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Session time is 20 or 30 minutes. User can open this form and submit it when the time of session is out. Users don't like exceptions

It's pretty standard to allow forms to expire after a certain amount of time. You can keep sessions open forever as that's a security hole.

As for the actual value, you can remove it from the session as soon as the second page has been processed. If the value is not there when the second page is hit, simply redirect to the first one again and show a message that says that it took too long time.

Your second option is to use `TempData` with is specifically designed for storing values between two pages. `TempData` cannot be accessed by the user.

The third option is of course to store the value in a database (to keep it as long as you want, between logins etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can store any object you like in the current session of the user. In your controller you can use:

```
// Save value to session
Session["MyVariableName"] = 32;

// Read value from session
int myVariable = (int)Session["MyVariableName"];
```

For more info regarding the session see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Session can time out.

Comment: If the timespan between these two requests is really that long you should definitly consider storing this in a database